# Safely generate a SAML2 token in a client application without install signing certificate

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, saml-2.0

I have a client application (windows) which the user is logged into. From this application, the user will want to access a remote website using single sign-on (SAML) and will be authenticated by Microsoft WIF. To do this the user, will click a button which opens a local web browser, generates a SAML token (containing username and roles, etc) and makes a HTTP POST to a remote website to access it, signing them in.

I want the user to be signed-in automatically, based on their credentials from the windows application.

I know roughly how to generate the SAML token, but presume this requires the signing certificate to be installed on the local PC, which would need to be installed into all PCs in my Company.

Installing this certificate doesn't seem quite right. How else can I safely allow users to generate a SAML token which will be accepted by the Service Provider (via single sign-on)?

UPDATE:

The user is not authenticated into the Windows Application using Windows Authentication (Kerberos), we make a custom SQL call to a database of username/password.

In the win app, we will know the username and their roles, so could generate claims from this, or pass it to a remote STS to generate and sign the SAML token. But again passing this data across to the STS seems totally wrong again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signing certificate must not be on the user desktop. Otherwise, any user could potentially generate a SAML token with the userid it wants.

What you want is a Secure Token Service (STS): an identity provider that will authenticate your user through Kerberos (as you want to re-use the identity of the logged-on user) and give you a signed SAML token.

All of this could be done when you open a web view in your application. The starting url should be the Identity Provider endpoint for IDP-initiated SSO, with a url parameter identifying the service you want to access.

Comment: The win app does not use Windows Authentication (Kerberos), so the STS could not use kerberos (I think).

Comment: I could pass the username from win app to the STS which would go off and populate the claims (roles) and generate/sign a SAML token to send out. But how could the win app safely pass the username to the STS in the first place?

Comment: You have to authenticate to the STS to securely pass the identity of the user. If your workstation is part of a Active Directory Domain, you can use Kerberos to authenticate to the STS.